# Vue js putting id to v-model

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js

I'm trying to create a question adder for my quiz. Each question has answers, containing IDs:

```js
var questions = [
{
    question: "1+1 is",
    answers: [ 
        { id: 0, answer: "1", correct: false }, 
        { id: 1, answer: "0", correct: false }, 
        { id: 2, answer: "2", correct: false } 
    ],
    correct: [2],
    selected: [],
    false: [0, 1]
}]
```

but I don't know how to create an array of objects with IDs. I know that `answercorrect`, `answerfalse1`/`2` are wrong, but what do I do instead?

Some HTML:

```html
<label>Otázka: <input v-model="question" type="text"></label><br><br>
<label>Správná odpověď: <input v-model="answercorrect" type="text"></label><br><br>
<label>Odpověď: <input v-model="answerfalse" type="text"></label><br><br>
<label>Odpověď: <input v-model="answerfalse2" type="text"></label>
```

JS:

```js
addQuestion()
{        
    if (this.question != "") 
    {
        this.questions.push(this.question);
        this.question = "";
        this.questions.push(this.answers[this.answercorrect, this.answerfalse, this.answerfalse2]);
        this.answercorrect = "";  
        this.answerfalse = "";
        this.answerfalse2 = ""; 
    }  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would create a function that generates a blank question object, containing an array of generated answer objects.

```js
let answerId = 0;
let questionId = 0;

const createAnswer = () => ({ id: answerId++, answer: '', correct: false })
const createQuestion = () => ({
  id: questionId++,
  question: '',
  answers: [createAnswer()],
})
```

A component would use those functions to add new questions and answers:

```js
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      questions: [createQuestion()],
    };
  },
  methods: {
    addQuestion() {
      this.questions.push(createQuestion())
    },
    addAnswer(q) {
      /**
       * Since the `answers` object is part of the `questions` object,
       * this takes a question as an argument, and adds a new `answer`
       * object to its `answers` array.
       */
      q.answers.push(createAnswer())
    },
  },
}
```

In the template, use [`v-for`](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html#Mapping-an-Array-to-Elements-with-v-for) to render the `questions`, and use [`v-on` button-click handlers](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/events.html) that bind to the component's `addQuestion()` and `addAnswer()`:

```html
<template>
  <div>
    <button @click="addQuestion">Add question</button>

    <fieldset class="question" v-for="q in questions" :key="q.id">
      <legend>Question: <input v-model="q.question" type="text" /></legend>

      <button @click="addAnswer(q)">Add answer</button>
      <label class="answer" v-for="answer in q.answers" :key="answer.id">
        Answer: <input type="text" v-model="answer.answer" />
        Correct: <input type="checkbox" v-model="answer.correct" />
      </label>
    </fieldset>
  </div>
</template>
```

[demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/data-binding-to-nested-data-in-vue-iov01?file=/src/components/QuizForm.vue)